# Fill xlsx file empty cell with results from a map using Java and Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, file-writing

I basically have 2 xlsx files, one with image url's and a product id, and one with a empty image url's and a product id.

I already load the contents I need to parse in the other file correctly, the parameter with the map contains all the info required.

So my question is, how can I write in the new file with the results from the mappings? I basically need to put the image url on the first column's index which contains the image urls for all the products.

Here is some sample code,

```
    private static void writeFile(Map<String, String> products) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("./data/stock_zonder_imageurls.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row currentRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                if(cell != null && cell.getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.STRING)) {
                    if(cell.getColumnIndex() == 2) {
                        String val = cell.getStringCellValue();

                        if(products.containsKey(val)) {
                            String image_url = products.get(val);
                            //here I need to write to the file the image url on column 0 of the specified $file with the $image_url
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? I would try `currentRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(image_url);`. Of course you also need writing out the `workbook` using `workbook.write` after all.

Comment: So adding the creation of the cell together with the value, and writing the workbook out to the same file wil modify it and update the file for all occurences that match the key.

Comment: do you want to create a new file or update the existing file ?. your requirement is not clear.

Comment: Update the existing file with the image urls that match the product key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the question, your requirement is a update the existing excel file.

try with following steps.

```
//create a row id and initialized
int rowId = 0;

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    ---- //another code
    rowId++;
    if(products.containsKey(val)) {
        String image_url = products.get(val);
        //assumed as first row is header
        Cell cell = datatypeSheet.getRow(rowId).getCell(0); //get the cell from relevant row (rowId) and first column (column index is a 0)
        cell.setCellValue(image_url); //set image_url into cell
    }
    ---- //another code
}
```

Comment: But will this keep all the other contents in the excel file too? Im looking to modify and update the file, not create new files.

Comment: I assume in that case ill have to copy all the other elements in aswell?

Comment: @KathyJuffer please refer above modified answer.

Comment: So the setCellValue will actually modify and update the file?

Comment: @KathyJuffer yep, try with above solution

Comment: Nothing happened, the file didn't get updated, this is what I have tried.

https://hastebin.com/epupehekox.java

Comment: Managed it to fix it with some more additions to your suggestions, thanks a bunch!

Here is the updated method which worked perfectly fine.

https://hastebin.com/niputocige.cs

Comment: sorry for the mistake. Please `rowId` increment by one in the while, not in if condition. updated the answer.